# ExtJS Combobox with TPL Issue

Tags: combobox, extjs4.2

I have followed a previous example to create a combobox with 'multiple' columns however, when I go to select an item it doesn't make a selection.  How do i enable selection of the items with a tpl?

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item" >{ntID} {PictureURL}</div></tpl>',
    editable: true,
    //autoSelect: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: 'userInfos',
    displayField: 'ntID',
    valueField: 'ntID',
    fieldLabel: 'Username',
    itemId: 'username'
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list item should be replaced with:

```
div class="x-boundlist-item"
```